# Get a variable from Javascript to Sql query in JSTL

Tags: javascript, sql, jakarta-ee, jstl

I developed in Java EE and I want to take a javascript variable (which I obtained from another jsp page mother) I want to use it in a query sql server in the same page pop1.jsp, here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var valeur= opener.document.getElementById("formulaireFournisseur").idfour.value;
function affectation(){
    var valeur;
      valeur= opener.document.getElementById("formulaireFournisseur").idfour.value;
      document.write(valeur);
       document.getElementById("form").champ.value=opener.document.getElementById("formulaireFournisseur").idfour.value;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<sql:query var="result" dataSource="Achat"> 

  Select * FROM dbo.Fournisseur WHERE nom LIKE ?

   </sql:query>       
  <sql:param> '%$valeur%' </sql:param> 
<table border="1">

       <!-- column headers -->
       <tr>
           <c:forEach var="columnName" items="${result.columnNames}">
               <th><c:out value="${columnName}"/></th>
               </c:forEach>
       </tr>
       <!-- column data -->

       <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rowsByIndex}">
           <tr id="${result.rowsByIndex}" ondblclick="SelectLigne(this);window.close() ">
               <c:forEach var="column" items="${row}">
                   <td><c:out value="${column}"/></td>
               </c:forEach>
           </tr>
       </c:forEach>
   </table>       
</body>
</html>
```

I want to recover $ value in the code of the SQL query and execute my sql mequete correctly.
please help me

Answer (score 0):

1. The sql-code is executed on the server.
2. After that, the page is generated and sent to the client requesting it.
3. The client browser will then process the javascript.

Your solution will not work. It tries to work in the opposite order. Also, as sql and javascript are executed on different machines (server and client) you will have to rewrite this.

You probably need to construct a form with the valeur value to submit to the server.

Comment: hello thank you for the answer, but I actually want to display the table query whene loading the popup?
is there another solution?
thank you